# Compiler returns Error C2593 'operator !=' is ambiguous

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cgal

I am currently trying to build my code in Visual Studio 2015. The compiler unfortunately does not hint at any fixes or describe the error any further.
Here is a segment of my code:

> ```
>     ArrangementBH_2::Face_iterator face_iterator;
>     ArrangementBH_2::Ccb_halfedge_const_circulator dcel_circulator;
>     ArrangementBH_2::Originating_curve_iterator ocurve_iterator;
>
>     for (face_iterator = current.faces_begin();
>         face_iterator != current.faces_end();
>         ++face_iterator)
>     {
>   
>         if (face_iterator->is_unbounded())
>         {
>             FaceStructs meta;
>             meta.bounded = false;
>             face_iterator->set_data(meta);
>             continue;
>         }
>
>
>
>         dcel_circulator = face_iterator->outer_ccb();
>         map<int, int> index_count;  //key=>polygonIndex, value=> number of referenced edge                  
>         set<int> edgePolygonSet;  //for edge facing infinity or hole (ie: edge that has only one and not two halfedge)
>       
>
>
>         do
>         {
>           int originalCurveCountt = 0;
>           int input_index;
>             for (ocurve_iterator = current.originating_curves_begin(dcel_circulator);
>                 ocurve_iterator != current.originating_curves_end(dcel_circulator);
>                 ++ocurve_iterator)
>             {
>                 int id = ocurve_iterator->source().id();
>                 input_index = edge_map[id];  //polygonindex
>                 
>                 if (index_count.count(input_index) == 0)
>                     index_count[input_index] = 1;
>                 else
>                     index_count[input_index]++;
>               originalCurveCountt++;
>             }
>           if (originalCurveCountt==1)
>           {
>               edgePolygonSet.insert(input_index);
>           }
>
>             dcel_circulator++;
>         }
>         while (dcel_circulator != face_iterator->outer_ccb());
> ```

The error shows up at the last line's while statement. The value types of dcel_circulator and face_iterator are halfedge and face respectively. They are both objects from the class template CGAL::Arrangement_2. face_iterator has a member function "outer_ccb()" which returns a circulator. ArrangementBH_2 is a class template from CGAL::Arrangement_2.

The output of the compilation /w the error message:

```
1>GetFaces.cpp(210): error C2593: 'operator !=' is ambiguous
1>  C:\dev\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\include\CGAL/HalfedgeDS_iterator.h(266): note: could be 'bool CGAL::_HalfedgeDS_facet_const_circ<CGAL::Arrangement_on_surface_2<CGAL::Arr_consolidated_curve_data_traits_2<GeomTraits_,CGAL::Arr_segment_2<Kernel_> *>,CGAL::Arr_bounded_planar_topology_traits_2<T,D>>::Halfedge,CGAL::I_Filtered_const_iterator<CGAL::internal::In_place_list_const_iterator<CGAL::Arr_halfedge<V,H,F>,Alloc>,CGAL::Arrangement_on_surface_2<CGAL::Arr_consolidated_curve_data_traits_2<GeomTraits_,CGAL::Arr_segment_2<Kernel_> *>,CGAL::Arr_bounded_planar_topology_traits_2<T,D>>::_Is_valid_halfedge,CGAL::internal::In_place_list_iterator<CGAL::Arr_halfedge<V,H,F>,Alloc>,CGAL::Arrangement_on_surface_2<CGAL::Arr_consolidated_curve_data_traits_2<GeomTraits_,CGAL::Arr_segment_2<Kernel_> *>,CGAL::Arr_bounded_planar_topology_traits_2<T,D>>::Halfedge,__int64,std::bidirectional_iterator_tag>,CGAL::Bidirectional_circulator_tag>::operator !=(const It &) const'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              GeomTraits_=Traits_2,
1>              Kernel_=Kernel,
1>              T=CGAL::Arr_consolidated_curve_data_traits_2<Traits_2,CGAL::Arr_segment_2<Kernel> *>,
1>              D=CGAL::Arr_face_extended_dcel<CGAL::Arr_consolidated_curve_data_traits_2<Traits_2,CGAL::Arr_segment_2<Kernel> *>,FaceStructs,CGAL::Arr_vertex_base<CGAL::Point_2<CGAL::Epeck>>,CGAL::Arr_halfedge_base<CGAL::_Curve_data_ex<CGAL::Arr_segment_2<Kernel>,CGAL::_Unique_list<CGAL::Arr_segment_2<Kernel> *>>>,CGAL::Arr_face_base>,
1>              V=CGAL::Arr_vertex_base<CGAL::Point_2<CGAL::Epeck>>,
1>              H=CGAL::Arr_halfedge_base<CGAL::_Curve_data_ex<CGAL::Arr_segment_2<Kernel>,CGAL::_Unique_list<CGAL::Arr_segment_2<Kernel> *>>>,
1>              F=CGAL::Arr_extended_face<CGAL::Arr_face_base,FaceStructs>,
1>              Alloc=std::allocator<CGAL::Arr_halfedge<CGAL::Arr_vertex_base<CGAL::Point_2<CGAL::Epeck>>,CGAL::Arr_halfedge_base<CGAL::_Curve_data_ex<CGAL::Arr_segment_2<Kernel>,CGAL::_Unique_list<CGAL::Arr_segment_2<Kernel> *>>>,CGAL::Arr_extended_face<CGAL::Arr_face_base,FaceStructs>>>,
1>              It=CGAL::I_Filtered_const_iterator<CGAL::internal::In_place_list_const_iterator<CGAL::Arr_halfedge<CGAL::Arr_vertex_base<CGAL::Point_2<CGAL::Epeck>>,CGAL::Arr_halfedge_base<CGAL::_Curve_data_ex<CGAL::Arr_segment_2<Kernel>,CGAL::_Unique_list<CGAL::Arr_segment_2<Kernel> *>>>,CGAL::Arr_extended_face<CGAL::Arr_face_base,FaceStructs>>,std::allocator<CGAL::Arr_halfedge<CGAL::Arr_vertex_base<CGAL::Point_2<CGAL::Epeck>>,CGAL::Arr_halfedge_base<CGAL::_Curve_data_ex<CGAL::Arr_segment_2<Kernel>,CGAL::_Unique_list<CGAL::Arr_segment_2<Kernel> *>>>,CGAL::Arr_extended_face<CGAL::Arr_face_base,FaceStructs>>>>,CGAL::Arrangement_on_surface_2<CGAL::Arr_consolidated_curve_data_traits_2<Traits_2,CGAL::Arr_segment_2<Kernel> *>,CGAL::Arr_bounded_planar_topology_traits_2<CGAL::Arr_consolidated_curve_data_traits_2<Traits_2,CGAL::Arr_segment_2<Kernel> *>,CGAL::Arr_face_extended_dcel<CGAL::Arr_consolidated_curve_data_traits_2<Traits_2,CGAL::Arr_segment_2<Kernel> *>,FaceStructs,CGAL::Arr_vertex_base<CGAL::Point_2<CGAL::Epeck>>,CGAL::Arr_halfedge_base<CGAL::_Curve_data_ex<CGAL::Arr_segment_2<Kernel>,CGAL::_Unique_list<CGAL::Arr_segment_2<Kernel> *>>>,CGAL::Arr_face_base>>>::_Is_valid_halfedge,CGAL::internal::In_place_list_iterator<CGAL::Arr_halfedge<CGAL::Arr_vertex_base<CGAL::Point_2<CGAL::Epeck>>,CGAL::Arr_halfedge_base<CGAL::_Curve_data_ex<CGAL::Arr_segment_2<Kernel>,CGAL::_Unique_list<CGAL::Arr_segment_2<Kernel> *>>>,CGAL::Arr_extended_face<CGAL::Arr_face_base,FaceStructs>>,std::allocator<CGAL::Arr_halfedge<CGAL::Arr_vertex_base<CGAL::Point_2<CGAL::Epeck>>,CGAL::Arr_halfedge_base<CGAL::_Curve_data_ex<CGAL::Arr_segment_2<Kernel>,CGAL::_Unique_list<CGAL::Arr_segment_2<Kernel> *>>>,CGAL::Arr_extended_face<CGAL::Arr_face_base,FaceStructs>>>>,CGAL::Arrangement_on_surface_2<CGAL::Arr_consolidated_curve_data_traits_2<Traits_2,CGAL::Arr_segment_2<Kernel> *>,CGAL::Arr_bounded_planar_topology_traits_2<CGAL::Arr_consolidated_curve_data_traits_2<Traits_2,CGAL::Arr_segment_2<Kernel> *>,CGAL::Arr_face_extended_dcel<CGAL::Arr_consolidated_curve_data_traits_2<Traits_2,CGAL::Arr_segment_2<Kernel> *>,FaceStructs,CGAL::Arr_vertex_base<CGAL::Point_2<CGAL::Epeck>>,CGAL::Arr_halfedge_base<CGAL::_Curve_data_ex<CGAL::Arr_segment_2<Kernel>,CGAL::_Unique_list<CGAL::Arr_segment_2<Kernel> *>>>,CGAL::Arr_face_base>>>::Halfedge,__int64,std::bidirectional_iterator_tag>
1>          ]
1>  C:\dev\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\include\CGAL/HalfedgeDS_iterator.h(264): note: or       'bool CGAL::_HalfedgeDS_facet_const_circ<CGAL::Arrangement_on_surface_2<CGAL::Arr_consolidated_curve_data_traits_2<GeomTraits_,CGAL::Arr_segment_2<Kernel_> *>,CGAL::Arr_bounded_planar_topology_traits_2<T,D>>::Halfedge,CGAL::I_Filtered_const_iterator<CGAL::internal::In_place_list_const_iterator<CGAL::Arr_halfedge<V,H,F>,Alloc>,CGAL::Arrangement_on_surface_2<CGAL::Arr_consolidated_curve_data_traits_2<GeomTraits_,CGAL::Arr_segment_2<Kernel_> *>,CGAL::Arr_bounded_planar_topology_traits_2<T,D>>::_Is_valid_halfedge,CGAL::internal::In_place_list_iterator<CGAL::Arr_halfedge<V,H,F>,Alloc>,CGAL::Arrangement_on_surface_2<CGAL::Arr_consolidated_curve_data_traits_2<GeomTraits_,CGAL::Arr_segment_2<Kernel_> *>,CGAL::Arr_bounded_planar_topology_traits_2<T,D>>::Halfedge,__int64,std::bidirectional_iterator_tag>,CGAL::Bidirectional_circulator_tag>::operator !=(const CGAL::_HalfedgeDS_facet_const_circ<CGAL::Arrangement_on_surface_2<CGAL::Arr_consolidated_curve_data_traits_2<GeomTraits_,CGAL::Arr_segment_2<Kernel_> *>,CGAL::Arr_bounded_planar_topology_traits_2<T,D>>::Halfedge,CGAL::I_Filtered_const_iterator<CGAL::internal::In_place_list_const_iterator<CGAL::Arr_halfedge<V,H,F>,Alloc>,CGAL::Arrangement_on_surface_2<CGAL::Arr_consolidated_curve_data_traits_2<GeomTraits_,CGAL::Arr_segment_2<Kernel_> *>,CGAL::Arr_bounded_planar_topology_traits_2<T,D>>::_Is_valid_halfedge,CGAL::internal::In_place_list_iterator<CGAL::Arr_halfedge<V,H,F>,Alloc>,CGAL::Arrangement_on_surface_2<CGAL::Arr_consolidated_curve_data_traits_2<GeomTraits_,CGAL::Arr_segment_2<Kernel_> *>,CGAL::Arr_bounded_planar_topology_traits_2<T,D>>::Halfedge,__int64,std::bidirectional_iterator_tag>,CGAL::Bidirectional_circulator_tag> &) const'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              GeomTraits_=Traits_2,
1>              Kernel_=Kernel,
1>              T=CGAL::Arr_consolidated_curve_data_traits_2<Traits_2,CGAL::Arr_segment_2<Kernel> *>,
1>              D=CGAL::Arr_face_extended_dcel<CGAL::Arr_consolidated_curve_data_traits_2<Traits_2,CGAL::Arr_segment_2<Kernel> *>,FaceStructs,CGAL::Arr_vertex_base<CGAL::Point_2<CGAL::Epeck>>,CGAL::Arr_halfedge_base<CGAL::_Curve_data_ex<CGAL::Arr_segment_2<Kernel>,CGAL::_Unique_list<CGAL::Arr_segment_2<Kernel> *>>>,CGAL::Arr_face_base>,
1>              V=CGAL::Arr_vertex_base<CGAL::Point_2<CGAL::Epeck>>,
1>              H=CGAL::Arr_halfedge_base<CGAL::_Curve_data_ex<CGAL::Arr_segment_2<Kernel>,CGAL::_Unique_list<CGAL::Arr_segment_2<Kernel> *>>>,
1>              F=CGAL::Arr_extended_face<CGAL::Arr_face_base,FaceStructs>,
1>              Alloc=std::allocator<CGAL::Arr_halfedge<CGAL::Arr_vertex_base<CGAL::Point_2<CGAL::Epeck>>,CGAL::Arr_halfedge_base<CGAL::_Curve_data_ex<CGAL::Arr_segment_2<Kernel>,CGAL::_Unique_list<CGAL::Arr_segment_2<Kernel> *>>>,CGAL::Arr_extended_face<CGAL::Arr_face_base,FaceStructs>>>
1>          ]
1>  C:\dev\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\include\CGAL/HalfedgeDS_iterator.h(262): note: or       'bool CGAL::_HalfedgeDS_facet_const_circ<CGAL::Arrangement_on_surface_2<CGAL::Arr_consolidated_curve_data_traits_2<GeomTraits_,CGAL::Arr_segment_2<Kernel_> *>,CGAL::Arr_bounded_planar_topology_traits_2<T,D>>::Halfedge,CGAL::I_Filtered_const_iterator<CGAL::internal::In_place_list_const_iterator<CGAL::Arr_halfedge<V,H,F>,Alloc>,CGAL::Arrangement_on_surface_2<CGAL::Arr_consolidated_curve_data_traits_2<GeomTraits_,CGAL::Arr_segment_2<Kernel_> *>,CGAL::Arr_bounded_planar_topology_traits_2<T,D>>::_Is_valid_halfedge,CGAL::internal::In_place_list_iterator<CGAL::Arr_halfedge<V,H,F>,Alloc>,CGAL::Arrangement_on_surface_2<CGAL::Arr_consolidated_curve_data_traits_2<GeomTraits_,CGAL::Arr_segment_2<Kernel_> *>,CGAL::Arr_bounded_planar_topology_traits_2<T,D>>::Halfedge,__int64,std::bidirectional_iterator_tag>,CGAL::Bidirectional_circulator_tag>::operator !=(std::nullptr_t) const'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              GeomTraits_=Traits_2,
1>              Kernel_=Kernel,
1>              T=CGAL::Arr_consolidated_curve_data_traits_2<Traits_2,CGAL::Arr_segment_2<Kernel> *>,
1>              D=CGAL::Arr_face_extended_dcel<CGAL::Arr_consolidated_curve_data_traits_2<Traits_2,CGAL::Arr_segment_2<Kernel> *>,FaceStructs,CGAL::Arr_vertex_base<CGAL::Point_2<CGAL::Epeck>>,CGAL::Arr_halfedge_base<CGAL::_Curve_data_ex<CGAL::Arr_segment_2<Kernel>,CGAL::_Unique_list<CGAL::Arr_segment_2<Kernel> *>>>,CGAL::Arr_face_base>,
1>              V=CGAL::Arr_vertex_base<CGAL::Point_2<CGAL::Epeck>>,
1>              H=CGAL::Arr_halfedge_base<CGAL::_Curve_data_ex<CGAL::Arr_segment_2<Kernel>,CGAL::_Unique_list<CGAL::Arr_segment_2<Kernel> *>>>,
1>              F=CGAL::Arr_extended_face<CGAL::Arr_face_base,FaceStructs>,
1>              Alloc=std::allocator<CGAL::Arr_halfedge<CGAL::Arr_vertex_base<CGAL::Point_2<CGAL::Epeck>>,CGAL::Arr_halfedge_base<CGAL::_Curve_data_ex<CGAL::Arr_segment_2<Kernel>,CGAL::_Unique_list<CGAL::Arr_segment_2<Kernel> *>>>,CGAL::Arr_extended_face<CGAL::Arr_face_base,FaceStructs>>>
1>          ]
1>  C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\shared\guiddef.h(197): note: or       'bool operator !=(const GUID &,const GUID &)'
1>  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\thread(219): note: or       'bool std::operator !=(std::thread::id,std::thread::id) noexcept'
1>  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\system_error(419): note: or       'bool std::operator !=(const std::error_condition &,const std::error_condition &) noexcept'
1>  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\system_error(412): note: or       'bool std::operator !=(const std::error_condition &,const std::error_code &) noexcept'
1>  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\system_error(405): note: or       'bool std::operator !=(const std::error_code &,const std::error_condition &) noexcept'
1>  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\system_error(398): note: or       'bool std::operator !=(const std::error_code &,const std::error_code &) noexcept'
1>  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\exception(354): note: or       'bool std::operator !=(const std::exception_ptr &,std::nullptr_t) throw()'
1>  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\exception(349): note: or       'bool std::operator !=(std::nullptr_t,const std::exception_ptr &) throw()'
1>  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\exception(344): note: or       'bool std::operator !=(const std::exception_ptr &,const std::exception_ptr &) throw()'
1>  C:\dev\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\include\CGAL/Interval_nt.h(329): note: or       'CGAL::Uncertain<bool> CGAL::Interval_nt<true>::operator !=(const CGAL::Interval_nt<true> &,const CGAL::Interval_nt<true> &)' [found using argument-dependent lookup]
1>  C:\dev\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\include\CGAL/Interval_nt.h(374): note: or       'CGAL::Uncertain<bool> CGAL::Interval_nt<true>::operator !=(double,const CGAL::Interval_nt<true> &)' [found using argument-dependent lookup]
1>  C:\dev\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\include\CGAL/Interval_nt.h(414): note: or       'CGAL::Uncertain<bool> CGAL::Interval_nt<true>::operator !=(const CGAL::Interval_nt<true> &,double)' [found using argument-dependent lookup]
1>  C:\dev\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\include\CGAL/Interval_nt.h(329): note: or       'CGAL::Uncertain<bool> CGAL::Interval_nt<false>::operator !=(const CGAL::Interval_nt<false> &,const CGAL::Interval_nt<false> &)' [found using argument-dependent lookup]
1>  C:\dev\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\include\CGAL/Interval_nt.h(374): note: or       'CGAL::Uncertain<bool> CGAL::Interval_nt<false>::operator !=(double,const CGAL::Interval_nt<false> &)' [found using argument-dependent lookup]
1>  C:\dev\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\include\CGAL/Interval_nt.h(414): note: or       'CGAL::Uncertain<bool> CGAL::Interval_nt<false>::operator !=(const CGAL::Interval_nt<false> &,double)' [found using argument-dependent lookup]
1>  C:\dev\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\include\CGAL/Mpzf.h(578): note: or       'bool CGAL::operator !=(const CGAL::Mpzf &,const CGAL::Mpzf &)' [found using argument-dependent lookup]
1>  GetFaces.cpp(210): note: while trying to match the argument list '(CGAL::_HalfedgeDS_facet_const_circ<CGAL::Arrangement_on_surface_2<CGAL::Arr_consolidated_curve_data_traits_2<GeomTraits_,CGAL::Arr_segment_2<Kernel_> *>,CGAL::Arr_bounded_planar_topology_traits_2<T,D>>::Halfedge,CGAL::I_Filtered_const_iterator<CGAL::internal::In_place_list_const_iterator<CGAL::Arr_halfedge<V,H,F>,Alloc>,CGAL::Arrangement_on_surface_2<CGAL::Arr_consolidated_curve_data_traits_2<GeomTraits_,CGAL::Arr_segment_2<Kernel_> *>,CGAL::Arr_bounded_planar_topology_traits_2<T,D>>::_Is_valid_halfedge,CGAL::internal::In_place_list_iterator<CGAL::Arr_halfedge<V,H,F>,Alloc>,CGAL::Arrangement_on_surface_2<CGAL::Arr_consolidated_curve_data_traits_2<GeomTraits_,CGAL::Arr_segment_2<Kernel_> *>,CGAL::Arr_bounded_planar_topology_traits_2<T,D>>::Halfedge,__int64,std::bidirectional_iterator_tag>,CGAL::Bidirectional_circulator_tag>, CGAL::_HalfedgeDS_facet_circ<CGAL::Arrangement_on_surface_2<CGAL::Arr_consolidated_curve_data_traits_2<GeomTraits_,CGAL::Arr_segment_2<Kernel_> *>,CGAL::Arr_bounded_planar_topology_traits_2<T,D>>::Halfedge,CGAL::I_Filtered_iterator<CGAL::internal::In_place_list_iterator<CGAL::Arr_halfedge<V,H,F>,Alloc>,CGAL::Arrangement_on_surface_2<CGAL::Arr_consolidated_curve_data_traits_2<GeomTraits_,CGAL::Arr_segment_2<Kernel_> *>,CGAL::Arr_bounded_planar_topology_traits_2<T,D>>::_Is_valid_halfedge,CGAL::Arrangement_on_surface_2<CGAL::Arr_consolidated_curve_data_traits_2<GeomTraits_,CGAL::Arr_segment_2<Kernel_> *>,CGAL::Arr_bounded_planar_topology_traits_2<T,D>>::Halfedge,__int64,std::bidirectional_iterator_tag>,CGAL::Bidirectional_circulator_tag>)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              GeomTraits_=Traits_2,
1>              Kernel_=Kernel,
1>              T=CGAL::Arr_consolidated_curve_data_traits_2<Traits_2,CGAL::Arr_segment_2<Kernel> *>,
1>              D=CGAL::Arr_face_extended_dcel<CGAL::Arr_consolidated_curve_data_traits_2<Traits_2,CGAL::Arr_segment_2<Kernel> *>,FaceStructs,CGAL::Arr_vertex_base<CGAL::Point_2<CGAL::Epeck>>,CGAL::Arr_halfedge_base<CGAL::_Curve_data_ex<CGAL::Arr_segment_2<Kernel>,CGAL::_Unique_list<CGAL::Arr_segment_2<Kernel> *>>>,CGAL::Arr_face_base>,
1>              V=CGAL::Arr_vertex_base<CGAL::Point_2<CGAL::Epeck>>,
1>              H=CGAL::Arr_halfedge_base<CGAL::_Curve_data_ex<CGAL::Arr_segment_2<Kernel>,CGAL::_Unique_list<CGAL::Arr_segment_2<Kernel> *>>>,
1>              F=CGAL::Arr_extended_face<CGAL::Arr_face_base,FaceStructs>,
1>              Alloc=std::allocator<CGAL::Arr_halfedge<CGAL::Arr_vertex_base<CGAL::Point_2<CGAL::Epeck>>,CGAL::Arr_halfedge_base<CGAL::_Curve_data_ex<CGAL::Arr_segment_2<Kernel>,CGAL::_Unique_list<CGAL::Arr_segment_2<Kernel> *>>>,CGAL::Arr_extended_face<CGAL::Arr_face_base,FaceStructs>>>
1>          ]
```

I am currently working on a small sample to isolate the error further. I will attach it to this question once I have it working.

Comment: It looks like the compiler can't decode how to compare a `Ccb_halfedge_const_circulator` with a `Ccb_halfedge_circulator`. Try declaring `dcel_circulator` as a `Ccb_halfedge_circulator` (or use `auto`). That way, the types will match, and there may be less ambiguity.

Answer (score 0):

Disabling "Conformance mode" might fix this in some cases ... but still seems like a bug though,

in your Visual Studio C++ Project open Project Properties :

```
Configuration Properties -> C/C++ -> Language -> Conformance mode -> (if its yes /permissive) change it to no
```